# Xcode main.m Sigabrt

Tags: xcode

Im trying to make an app and this error message comes up every time i try to simulate the app.

What does this mean ?

```
Thread 1:Signal SIGABRT
```

it comes up at the side of

```
    {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Every time i try to simulate my app it comes up ? and it wont let me simulate my app atall ???

Help me please .

Comment: It sounds like the simulator is in a bad state and didn't close cleanly.  Have you tried restart XCode?  Does this issue happen after a clean reboot?

Comment: i have the same issue, did you managed to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

in your simulator

```
Simulator --> reset the content and rules.... (or renitialiser le contenu et les regles...)
```

then close the simulator

do a `clean` of your project and `run` it